# Dynamically create new object of class with all attributes from empty object of the same class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to dynamically create a new `Object` with all properties of the `class` from an empty object of the same `class` without default values? The function should take any empty Object, detect the class of the object and create a new empty object of the same class but with all available properties of the `class`.

**example:**

```
export class Test {
  private prop_1: string;
  private prop_2: number;
  private prop_3: boolean;
}
```

**input:**
`let original = {}; // (Emtpy Object of class Test)`

**output:**

```
let new = {
      prop_1: null/undefined, 
      prop_2: null/undefined, 
      prop_3: null/undefined
    } // (new Object of class Test with all properties)`
```

is it somehow to create a new object of the class Test from an Object {} of the class TEST? It is not important what values there are, it just matters that all aviable properties are there

I tried `Object.create()` and some other stuff but nothing works...

**EDIT:**
I edited the snippets above to hopefully clarify my question. The solution with iterating of the `Object.keys()` array doesn´t work since there are no keys in an empty object. The original object is empty but the class is known!

Comment: how can final `object` you want have all the properties. Since, they are all private.

Comment: Yes, you just create a JSON object as a template.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(obj).forEach(v => obj[v] = null)` after new object creation

Comment: `let original = {};` should be `let original = new Test()`